# How to set tooltip toFixed(4) when using mode: index

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvgdn.png)

Like in the image, it's a official stacked bar example, how can i make the tooltip show 4 decimals when i am using mode: index?

Show 4 decimals

I've tried with callbacks, but it seemed will be mixed and get wrong tooltip with mode: index